# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'startswith' error

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to use `startswith` to sort certain parts of a data file so I can plot them on matplotlib by their name. I use:

```py
mint = open('/Users/brand/Desktop/datafile.txt')
str = ps.DataFrame(mint)
a = str.startswith('MS')
plt.scatter(color[a], light[a], c = 'blue')
b = str.startswith('BH')
plt.scatter(color[b], light[b], c = 'red')
c = str.startswith('RH')
plt.scatter(color[c], light[c], c = 'green')
d = str.startswith('RGB')
plt.scatter(color[d], light[d], c = 'purple')
e = str.startswith('AGB')
plt.scatter(color[e], light[e], c = 'pink')
```

But every single time I run it using a different module to open the file, it always has the error that : `'            ' object has no attribute 'startswith'`.

So what object DOES have an attribute to `startswith` that I can use?

Comment: Do you have some small sample data that we could use to actually run your code?

Answer (score 5):

rename your dataframe to `df_str` since `str` is a keyword in python. and do `df_str.str.startswith()` to apply your string methods

```
mint = open('/Users/brand/Desktop/datafile.txt')
df_str = ps.DataFrame(mint)[0]
a = df_str.str.startswith('MS')
plt.scatter(color[a], light[a], c = 'blue')
b = df_str.str.startswith('BH')
plt.scatter(color[b], light[b], c = 'red')
c = df_str.str.startswith('RH')
plt.scatter(color[c], light[c], c = 'green')
d = df_str.str.startswith('RGB')
plt.scatter(color[d], light[d], c = 'purple')
e = df_str.str.startswith('AGB')
plt.scatter(color[e], light[e], c = 'pink')
```

Edit: changed `df_str = ps.DataFrame(mint)` to `df_str = ps.DataFrame(mint)[0]`
to convert Dataframe to Series

Comment: This seems to work to convert dataframe to series, however now there is a new error with this line            :                                                                                                                     
        plt.scatter(color[a], light[a], c = 'blue')

Comment: the error reads : IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 459 but corresponding boolean dimension is 460

Comment: Your color array is 459 while your mint data has 460 rows. you can try  plt.scatter(color[a[:-1]], light[a[:-1]], c = 'blue') but this might not be correct. I will need to know what color and light array is and where you are getting extra rows froms

Answer (score 0):

The `startswith` attribute is made to be used on a string object.
 See documentation of the function here : [startswith()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith)
So it's totally normal that you can't call it on a DataFrame object

Comment: is there a way I could call in just a regular text file ?

Comment: Could you provide us an example of the file you are trying to use ?

Comment: MS_268004 
BHeB_b_268109 
AGB_268622 
RHeB_b_275281 
MS_328100 
RHeB_b_328107 
MS_328204 
BHeB_b_328250 
RGB_328305 
BHeB_b_329633

Comment: things like this in a single column where there are different types

Comment: it is a text file